# ASP.NET 3.5 properties' private member access within class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, properties

I have read about how in ASP.NET 3.5 you can declare properties in C#

```
public DateTime DisplayDate
{
     get;
}
```

instead of

```
private DateTime _displayDate
public DateTime DisplayDate
{
     get {return _displayDate;}
}
```

[like this post explains.](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/03/08/new-c-orcas-language-features-automatic-properties-object-initializers-and-collection-initializers.aspx)

My question is, within the class, how do I access the private variable?

For example instead of this

```
public MyClass(DateTime myDisplayDate)
{ _displayDate = myDisplayDate; }
```

What should I assign to?
Is it the public property?

```
public MyClass(DateTime myDisplayDate)
{ DisplayDate = myDisplayDate; }
```

Is this Correct?

Comment: you always need to declare both the getter and the setter with c# 3.0 automatic properties - see answers below - the trick is to mark the setter as privte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public DateTime DisplayDate
{
     get; private set;
}

public MyClass(DateTime myDisplayDate)
{ 
    this.DisplayDate = myDisplayDate; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Automatic Properties like this (which aren't limited to ASP.NET) are there so you don't have to deal with the private field. If you want to set the property's value, use the property itself and add a private setter (so only your class can set it)

```
public DateTime DisplayDate
{
    get; 
    private set;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You always need to declare both the getter and the setter with c# 3.0 automatic properties - see the other answers - the trick is to mark the setter as private.

```
public Foo { get; private set; }
```